# Angular PrimeNG Checkbox Model Driven wrong display

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng, display, angular-reactive-forms

I am using PrimeNG with the checkbox in the Model Driven angular(5) style.
I used the solution of this issue to make it worked https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2906
I used

```
<div *ngFor="let c of list">
<p-checkbox  [value]="c" [label]="c.name"
[formControl]="groupForm.controls['user']">
</p-checkbox>
</div>
```

I get correctly the infos in my post the issue is on the display, the first issue is the label is displayed below the checkbox and not on it side.
The second issue is when the checkbox is checked I get an extra check sign between the checkbox and the label. [checkbox view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcjBp.png)
I don't get any error in the console.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Can you please create a Plunker ?

Comment: I tried but didn't succeed. I actually forgot I was using bootstrap at the same time for my theme. So I guess primeng do its job but bootstrap probably add some css and make the weird display. I'll try to remove the bootstrap part of checkbox or switch to the bootstrap checkbox even if prefer the primeng.